# Placing 5 figures in 3 rows

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have five figures I want arranged in three rows of 2, 2 and 1. The first row contains 2 figures (like I want), but for some reason the next three figures are placed in their own rows. I cannot figure out why, I have tried adding \par\medskip which I have seen someone suggest, or combining subfigures and minipage environments, but that hasn't worked either.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \captionsetup{width=0.7\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxRugo.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:time1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxFormFac.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:time2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxVert.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:time3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxReg.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:time3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxPerimAreaRat.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:time3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\textit{Boxplots}}
    \label{fig:time}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: your last three subfig are specified to be `\linewidth` wide (and you have a word-space between them) so naturally they have to be one per line.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.. However even if I remove \linewidth, or I set it to 0.5 like the two top ones, they are still each in their own row. I didn't change anything in the top two subfigures, but when I recompiled, they are also in their own row.. Any tips?

Comment: I now recompiled again, and it works with 0.5\linewidth. I have no idea why it works now and didn't earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking to set the last three boxes at `\linewidth`, so they occupy the whole line.

Use `0.49\columnwidth` to leave some space between the figures on the same line and don't use `width=70mm` and `scale=0.3`, but `width=\textwidth`, so the image will be as wide as allowed by `subfigure`.

If you want the caption text to be in italics, use the appropriate setup, instead of adding explicit formatting instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % <--- remove demo
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{textfont=it}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxRugo.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxFormFac.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxVert.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxReg.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time4}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxPerimAreaRat.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time5}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Boxplots}
\label{fig:time}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to add `\medskip` between the rows; if you also add a top level `\centering` (after `\begin{figure}[htp]`), you'd get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{textfont=it}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxRugo.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxFormFac.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time2}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxVert.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxReg.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time4}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxPerimAreaRat.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:time5}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Boxplots}
\label{fig:time}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the `subfloatrow` environment, from `floatrow`, it works. Note the syntax is slightly different:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\floatsetup{capposition = below, floatrowsep =qquad,}
\centering
\ffigbox{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\centering
\ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption{}}{%
\includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxRugo.png}}
\ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption{}}{%
\includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxFormFac.png}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\vskip4ex
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption{}}{%
\includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxVert.png}%
}
\ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption{}}{%
\includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxReg.png}%
}
\end{subfloatrow}
\vskip4ex
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\textwidth]{\caption{}}%
{\includegraphics[width=70mm,scale=.3]{Figures/07-Appendix/BoxPlots/BoxPerimAreaRat.png}%
}
\end{subfloatrow}}{
\caption{\textit{Boxplots}}
\label{fig:time}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]